# Django makemigrations: Makemigration not detect fields, only creates id filed

Tags: django, makemigrations

my problem is about makemigrations, it not detect fields and only creates  id and foreignkey field.
I added studentapp to INSTALLED_APP:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'studentapp.apps.StudentappConfig'
]
```

and models.py has:
from django.db import models

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=True, ),
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True),



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class  Student(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="students", default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True, blank=True),
    date_born = models.DateField(),
    hobbi= models.CharField(max_length=100,),
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True),


    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

then I run command: `python manage.py makemigrations studentapp`
result of command:

```
Migrations for 'studentapp':
  studentapp\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Department
    - Create model Student
```

newly created migration files  (0001) only have id field and foreignkey field.
code in migrations 0001:

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-04-03 08:03

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

   dependencies = [
    ]

   operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Department',
            fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, 
   primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
    ),
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Student',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, 
  primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('department', models.ForeignKey(default=None, 
  on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, 
  related_name='students', to='studentapp.department')),
        ],
    ),
  ]
```

Comment: This is happening because you have commas at the end of all your field definitions - this converts the assignment into a tuple, which Django will not recognise as a field. Remove all the commas at the end of each line.

Comment: Thank you very much, I deleted as per your words and it ran successfully. I will learn from it for the next time.